# Adding constant to dataframe column conditional on other column

Tags: r

I want to add a constant to rows of a new column that match a certain condition in another column.

My simulated data:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "d"), 
                 var2 = c("b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c"), 
                 var2 = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "c", "c", "a")), 
            .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
            row.names = c(NA, 8L), 
            class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this:

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    b    c
2    b    b    c
3    c    a    c
4    a    b    c
5    a    b    d
6    a    c    c
7    a    a    c
8    d    c    a
```

Now I would like to add a `newvar` that increases by a value of 1 if `var1` equals `a`, increase it further by 1 if `var2` equals `b` and increase it further by 1 if `var3` equals `c`. That is, my data should look like:

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3 newvar
1    a    b    c      3
2    b    b    c      2
3    c    a    c      1
4    a    b    c      3
5    a    b    d      2
6    a    c    c      2
7    a    a    c      2
8    d    c    a      0
```

I have tried the following, but it will only replace the values with 1, not increase them by 1:

```
df$newvar[df$var1 == "a"] <- +1
df$newvar[df$var1 == "b"] <- +1
df$newvar[df$var1 == "c"] <- +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` in `dplyr` and count the number of conditions that are satisfied for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_var = sum(c(var1 == "a", var2 == "b" , var3 == "c")))

#  var1  var2  var3  new_var
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
#1 a     b     c           3
#2 b     b     c           2
#3 c     a     c           1
#4 a     b     c           3
#5 a     b     d           2
#6 a     c     c           2
#7 a     a     c           2
#8 d     c     a           0
```

---

Or base R method

```
df$new_var <- Reduce("+", list(df$var1 == "a", df$var2 == "b", df$var3 == "c"))
```

Comment: Accepted this as the `Reduce` approach seems most efficient to me.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way following your path and using base R is:

```
df$newVar = 0
df$newVar[df$var1 == "a"] <- df$newVar[df$var1 == "a"] +1
df$newVar[df$var2 == "b"] <- df$newVar[df$var2 == "b"] +1
df$newVar[df$var3 == "c"] <- df$newVar[df$var3 == "c"] +1
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarified my misunderstanding of R. However, I think it is ultimately not the optimal solution (too much code).

Answer (score 1):

Another way that uses **ifelse** and **mutate** instead of the **rowwise** solution above would be:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df %>% mutate(newVar = ifelse(var1 == "a",1,0) + ifelse(var2 == "b",1,0) + 
                           ifelse(var3 == "c",1,0))
```

Then you can adjust the constants to any value you like. If you want to include the new column in your dataframe just assign the result of mutate to your dataframe:

```
    df <- df %>% 
           mutate(newVar = ifelse(var1 == "a",1,0) + ifelse(var2 ==
                    "b",1,0) + ifelse(var3 == "c",1,0))
```

Comment: This works, but since I am new to `dplyr`: What do I have to change to add the variable to the actual `df`?

Comment: The mutate function (like all dplyr verbs, e.g. select, filter, group_by,...) returns a new dataframe so you just have to assign the outcome to your dataframe. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df$newVar <- rowSums(df == c('a', 'b', 'c')[col(df)])
df$newVar
#[1] 3 2 1 3 2 2 2 0
```